# Not able to handle custom notification in Flutter Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have create a custom notification using flutter_local_notification package , when I
send notification using FCM, two notifications are visible in both foreground and background state of application. When I click on FCM generated notification its works as usual , but while clicking on custom background notification my app start but am not able to run my logics, so please help me in handling the background custom notification

On clicking background custom notification it shows below info

> Attempted to start a duplicate background isolate. Returning...

```
class NotificationService {
  static final NotificationService _notificationService =
      NotificationService._private();
  NotificationService._private();
  factory NotificationService() => _notificationService;

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  final AndroidNotificationChannel _androidChannel =
      const AndroidNotificationChannel(
          'high_importance_channel', // id
          'Notifications', // title
          description: 'important notification channel', // description
          importance: Importance.high,
          playSound: true);

  final AndroidInitializationSettings _initializationSettingsAndroid =
      const AndroidInitializationSettings(
    'app_icon',
  );

  ///This functions initializes Flutterlocalnotificationplugin with required settings and channels
  initialize() async {
    AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin? resp =
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();

    await resp!.createNotificationChannel(_androidChannel);
    resp.requestPermission();

    var initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: _initializationSettingsAndroid);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: _handleForegroundNotification,
        onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:
            _handleBackgroundNotification);
  }

  /// This function create the custom notifcation.
  /// before calling this function , firebaseLocalNotification instance should be initialized
  showNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
    var initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: _initializationSettingsAndroid);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: _handleForegroundNotification,
        onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:
            _handleBackgroundNotification);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        1123,
        message.data['title'],
        message.data['body'],
        const NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            '1123',
            'channel.name',
            channelDescription: 'channel.description',
            color: Colors.blue,
            playSound: true,
          ),
        ));
  }
}

///This functions handle background notification press and performs given instructions
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
_handleBackgroundNotification(NotificationResponse response) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: "backgrrrround call nice no",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0);
}

///This functions handel foregroud notification press and performs given instruction
_handleForegroundNotification(NotificationResponse response) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: "Forerground call nice no",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0);
}
```

and another class for managing FCM

```
class FCMService {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  String? fcmToken;

  ///This function initialized FCM and start stream of token,foregroundmessage,backgroundmessage
  initialize() async {
    fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    debugPrint(fcmToken);
    _listenToTokenStream();
    _listenToForegroundMessage();
  }

  // /Handle  background but not teminated app notification press
  _listenToOnMessageOpenedApp() {
    //when
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      print("FCM>>>>>>>> backgroud");
    });
  }

  /// Request permission for higher sdk version
  _requestNotificationPermission() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    debugPrint('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
  }

  /// listen to foreground message recieved from FCM
  _listenToForegroundMessage() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      NotificationService().showNotification(message);
    });
  }

  ///Listen to streamm of token when token expires helps us to updat it
  _listenToTokenStream() {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((token) {
      fcmToken = token;
      debugPrint(fcmToken);
    }).onError((e) {
      debugPrint("token refresh failed");
    });
  }
}

///listen background message recieve from FCM , DO NOT: perform heavy task in background
///otherwise your process may get killed

Future<void> fcmBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // await NotificationService().initialize();
  NotificationService().showNotification(message);
}
```

main method :

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FCMService().initialize();
  NotificationService().initialize();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(fcmBackgroundMessageHandler);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should listen to background messages on FCM initialization But you are doing it on main. SO remove that and add the option in FCM initialization.

I have updated your code with the required updates.

```html
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FCMService().initialize();
  NotificationService().initialize();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

/// fcm background message handler
Future<void> fcmBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print(message.notification!.title);
  // NotificationService().showNotification(message);
}

class FCMService {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  String? fcmToken;

  ///This function initialized FCM and start stream of token,foregroundmessage,backgroundmessage
  initialize() async {
    fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    debugPrint(fcmToken);
    _listenToTokenStream();
    _listenToForegroundMessage();
    _listenToBackgroundMessage();
  }
  
  /// handle push notification events on background
  void handlePushNotificationBackgroundEvents() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(fcmBackgroundMessageHandler);
  }

  // /Handle  background but not teminated app notification press
  _listenToOnMessageOpenedApp() {
    //when
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      print("FCM>>>>>>>> backgroud");
    });
  }

  /// Request permission for higher sdk version
  _requestNotificationPermission() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    debugPrint('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
  }

  /// listen to foreground message recieved from FCM
  _listenToForegroundMessage() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      NotificationService().showNotification(message);
    });
  }

  ///Listen to streamm of token when token expires helps us to updat it
  _listenToTokenStream() {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((token) {
      fcmToken = token;
      debugPrint(fcmToken);
    }).onError((e) {
      debugPrint("token refresh failed");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thiers no issue in handling fcm generated notification ,  am not able to handle my custom notification click , it just open the application. I want my code to be executed when background notification generated is clicked